# What happen if all the carbon-14 atoms in a person body decays at once?

Tags: estimation, radioactivity, biology

What happens if all the carbon-14 atoms in a persons body decays at once? Would they die or will they be unaffected?

Answer (score 39):

There is about 1 radioactive $^{14}$C atom for every $10^{12}$ $^{12}$C atoms. With a half-life of 5730 years, this means there are usually about 0.2 decays per gramme of carbon per second.

Carbon is about [18% of your body mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_the_human_body), so an 80 kg adult would have about 14 kg of carbon and $7\times 10^{14}$ $^{14}$C atoms. If these all decayed in say one second, the dose rate would be $1.9\times 10^4$ Ci

To estimate the effects, we could assume all the beta particles are absorbed and that each has an energy of about 0.1 MeV. This gives an absorbed energy of just **11 Joules** of energy. Totally negligible in energetic terms.

In terms of absorbed radiation the quantity is about 11 J/80 kg = 0.14 Grays and for beta particles, roughly the same number of Sieverts, i.e. 140 mSv.

This is roughly the same radiation dose you would get from $\sim$[20 CT scans](https://www.radiologyinfo.org/en/info/safety-xray) or about the same as a few decades worth of exposure to ambient radiation in the environment and is enough to [raise your long-term cancer risk slightly](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-japan-quake-radiation-idUSTRE72E14R20110315) (a few per cent) but likely not enough to cause acute radiation poisoning.

Comment: +1 for actually looking at the radiation dose

Comment: +1 CT scans vary a lot, though - 140mSv is actually a pretty large dose, and is about 70 times higher than a simple head CT scan (about 2mSv).  Other types of CT scan (ie: heart-attack diagnosis, abdomen/pelvis) can be higher and closer to the value you're quoting (around 14mSv).  140mSv is actually almost three times the annual exposure limit for US radiation workers (50mSv).  The [Fukushima 50](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fukushima_50) had a number of workers that received doses in the 100-180mSv range, so that's maybe the closest comparison for OP to consider.

Comment: @J... Exactly. A not very extreme exposure leading to perhaps a few per cent increase in cancer risk. CT scan info is from https://www.radiologyinfo.org/en/info/safety-xray , and 10 is a round number. Call it 20 if you like.

Comment: @ProfRob I'd say it's a bit more serious than that, especially as an acute dose.  A few decades of background radiation happens over a long time.  All at once, though, is a different matter.  Two plant workers at Fukushima, for example, were exposed in an accident to 170-180mSv and [had to be taken to hospital for radiation burns](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2011/mar/24/japan-nuclear-plant-workers-hospital).  That's a bit more than an abstract few-percent increase in future risk - that's a serious acute effect.  140mSv is a big dose, especially when it's coming from *inside* the body.

Comment: @J... the fact that it is inside the body was accounted for by saying everything is  absorbed. Sieverts are a measure of effective absorbed dose. The same article you quote notes that workers were allowed exposures up to 250 mSv in a year. The burns were caused because the 180 mSv was external to a small area, not distributed throughout the body. 11 J over your entire body isn't burning anything

Comment: @ProfRob .11J anywhere isn't much of anything.  It's 10,000x less energy than in a single match, and half a second of output from a 200mw balloon popping laser.  Even if you concentrated it onto a small enough area to cause a burn I'm skeptical that the affected area would be large enough to be noticeable.

Comment: @ProfRob The exposure limit was raised from 100mSv to 250mSv strictly in wake of the Fukushima crisis.  Many of the workers [rejected this change](https://web.archive.org/web/20110410215931/http://mdn.mainichi.jp/mdnnews/news/20110410p2g00m0dm011000c.html) and continued to work to the previous 100mSv rule, though.  I think, if anything, that's pretty telling that we're into a dose range that is starting to become a bit scary.  140mSv is not an exposure that anyone should take lightly, imo.  It's not likely to be immediately fatal, but it is a very serious amount of radiation.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight an *external* beta source deposits all its energy in the outer thin layer of skin and it can be "burned" by such exposures. As the article cited by J... shows.

Comment: @ProfRob The seriousness of it being "inside the body" is also not just about the absorbed dose, but it's about *where* it's absorbed.  C14 will be distributed throughout all of the body's tissues, including inside bone, which normally protects sensitive blood-producing cells, inside the brain, etc.  Inside the body there will be much higher absorbed dose in critical and sensitive organs and tissues.

Comment: @J... What people "feel" or "believe" about radiation doses is of no physics interest. It's not likely to be immediately fatal or long-term fatal.  Yes, the equivalent of 20 CT scans is significant.140 mSv is a modest, but measurable, few per cent increment to your long-term cancer risk. The statements in my answer are factual AFAIK.

Comment: @ProfRob I agree your numbers are in line with current medical knowledge.  I'm just saying that OP's circumstance is highly irregular and not the type of exposure that medical science has a lot of experience with (ie: entire body becoming acutely radioactive).  That the mode of exposure is so different, and is absorbing dose inside all the body's critical organs, we might expect the physical consequences to fall on the pessimistic side of our stochastic models.

Comment: For C-14 decay, $\lambda\approx 3.8332×10^{-12}\,s^{-1}$. So the probability of all $7×10^{14}$ atoms decaying in 1 second is incomprehensibly small. The base 10 log of the probability is $\approx-8×10^{15}$. If you wrote the probability itself in a font with characters 1 mm wide, the zeros would stretch over 53 AU.

Answer (score 6):

Carbon-14 has a relative abundance to Carbon-12 of about 0.0000000001% (one part per trillion). The average human body has about 15 kg of Carbon give or take, meaning about 1.5 micrograms of Carbon-14. That's 107 nanomoles of carbon, or about 6.444×10^16 atoms (1/3000th a grain of sand). When a Carbon-14 atom decays into a Nitrogen-14 atom via beta decay, it loses 0.001% of its mass in the form of an electron and kinetic energy (156.5 keV of kinetic energy to be precise). The total amount of kinetic energy released into the body if all 6.444×10^16 atoms in it were to decay would be 1.6 kJ.

It's hard to say exactly how much damage that would do to the body, but it would definitely do something. That's about the energy your body releases in 15 seconds, so the damage that would be done entirely depends on how quickly the decay happens. If its over a few seconds, likely nothing would happen. If its instantaneous, that would be like a very sudden hotflash that could damage some tissue, though even that wouldn't kill you. The dangerous thing you'd have to worry about is cancer. To give perspective, only about 20 atoms of carbon would decay in a given cell, and only a 20% chance that in a given cell one of those would be in a DNA molecule. About 1 in every 5 of your cells will likely have a single base pair destroyed, meaning one letter of your genetic code. While these happen all the time, if this scenario occured over one second, it would be about 200,000 times higher than the normal rate of mutation per second. That wouldn't guarantee cancer of course, but I wouldn't volunteer for this to happen to me any time soon.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But will the missing amount of carbon have any significant impact?

Comment: The carbon doesn't go missing, it just becomes a nitrogen atom with approximately the same mass. Any molecule with one of the carbons would be damaged yes, but thats only a very small fraction of molecules. As I say in my answer, 1 in ever 5 cells will have a DNA molucule that will be effected.

Comment: I'd guess there is a good chance the radiation would kill you -- the energy corresponds to a dose of about 20 J/kg, so about 20 Sievert, which would give acute sickness.

Comment: Note that the 156.5 keV KE is split randomly between the electron & the antineutrino (plus a tiny amount to the N-14 daughter), the mean KE is around 49.5 keV. See https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/65816 for the decay energy curve.

Comment: You can correct your energy output to $1.6$ kJ $(49.5/156.5) = 0.5$ kJ. Make a rough approximation that your body is made of water, The specific heat of water is $4186$ kJ/kg/$^o$C. Assume you used [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_body_weight) average human mass value of $62$ kg. Then that much energy would raise your temperature $1.6$ micro$^o$C.

Comment: Compared [this other answer on this page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/676033/44126), your estimate of the carbon-14 mass is higher by a factor of 100, and your estimate of the total decay energy is higher by a factor of 1000. You have (v1) at least one unit conversion error: “kilo” times $10^{-12}$ is “nano,” but you go from kilograms of carbon to micrograms of carbon-14. I haven’t done the energy calculation, but give it a second look.

Comment: One trillionth of 15 kG is *not* 1.5 micrograms, it is 15 *nano*grams.  That's off by a factor of 100.

Comment: This answer is busted.

Answer (score -3):

More important than the radiation dose is that the Carbon-14 would decay to Nitrogen-14 and random proteins, cellular structures, RNA and DNA would no longer function. There might be secondary effects, such as The Bends, a.k.a decompression sickness, from nitrogen in the blood, or other diseases. I would hesitate to predict anything but a painful lingering death.

Comment: I doubt you'd get the bends from 14 nanograms of nitrogen.

Comment: OK, then. I read the previous answers and I was more impressed with the possible biological effects than radiation. Maybe we need a volunteer, but how could this be accomplished?